# BotFramework: Issue with session.dialogData in Promise consuming function

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am struggling with issue related to assigning `session.dialogData` attribute in `.then()` Promise consuming function. I need to implement business logic when some data is saved in MongoDB on one waterfall step with function which return ObjectID of inserted document and then to save this value in attribute of `session.dialogData`. Then I need to use value of this `session.dialogData` attribute in the next waterfall step. The issue is this attribute becomes `undefined` when I try to use this attribute on second step.

What I am doing wrong here? This is the first time I am using BotFramework. Here is the code example bellow:

```
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.phoneNumber = results.response;

    session.sendTyping();

    // Function with Promise which saves customer data in MongoDB and resolve ObjectId of inserted document   
    saveCustomerData (customerDataObj)
        .then(function (objectid) {
            console.log(objectid.toString());
            session.dialogData.insCustomerObjId = objectid.toString(); // value is assigned successfully
        }
    );
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.insCustomerObjId = results.response.entity;

    console.log (session.dialogData.insCustomerObjId) // <-- !!! undefined !!!

    // some logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take control of the waterfall step advancement, which is done by including a **next** callback parameter in the waterfall step function. The waterfall will step to next step when that callback is called.

For more info, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-waterfall#advance-the-waterfall)

Following code snippet should solve your problem:

```
// pass an extra next callback parameter
function (session, results, next) {
    session.dialogData.phoneNumber = results.response;
    session.sendTyping();

    saveCustomerData (customerDataObj)
        .then(function (objectid) {
            console.log(objectid.toString());
            session.dialogData.insCustomerObjId = objectid.toString();
            next(); // call the next callback, indicating go to the next step
        }
    );
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.insCustomerObjId = results.response.entity;
    console.log (session.dialogData.insCustomerObjId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful for me to resolve my issue. But could you explain the magic with `next()` and preserving value of `session.dialogData` attribute? I've read doc carefully but did not find the answer.